# How to dynamically add items to a ListView based on a List on XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am trying to create a `<ListView>` with XAML. The list is supposed to show the contents of a list of the class `Task`.

```
taskView.ItemsSource = company.tasks;
```

The version of XAML I am using is the one contemplated on MAUI therefore most tutorials show elements than are not included in the XAML version used.

I tried to do it as following:

```
        <ListView x:Name="taskView"
      Margin="120,0,0,60"
      ItemsSource="{Binding tasks}"
      ItemSelected="taskView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding name}"/>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding status}"/>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding dedaline}"/>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

But it did not work. It would neither open the app nor throw an exception.

If I leave only one `<TextCell>`, it opens and shows (only the name). How can I show more details?

Here is the class `Task`:

```
    public class Task
    {
        public Task(string name, List<string> departments, Status status, DateOnly deadline, string description)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.departments = departments;
            this.status = status;
            this.deadline = deadline;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public string name { get; private set; }
        public List<string> departments { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
        public Status status { get; private set; }
        public DateOnly deadline { get; private set; }
        public Employee? author { get; set; }
        public string description { get; private set; }
        public List<Employee> employees { get; private set; } = new List<Employee>();
    }
```

I am fairly new to XAML and would candidly appreciate some help.
Thank you.

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?  Did you get an error or exception?  Are you not seeing any rows in the ListView?  The title implies the problem is adding new items "dynamically" but the code you posted does not reflect that.  Finally, you are both setting the `ItemsSource` in the XAML **and** in the code.  Pick one approach or the other, do not use both.

Comment: @Jason the did not work means that It didn't even debug. It would instantly stop debugging but wouldn't show any exceptions. Thank you for the suggestion of adding on only one, I didn't know. My code doesn't reflect what I'm trying to do since I have no clue on how to do it in the first place. That's why I am asking for help

Comment: again, that does not tell me anything useful.  "Instantly stop debugging" - are you saying it is crashing?  Or just not displaying what you expect?

Comment: @Jason I don't know. It was acting weird. It's like I clicked on the button but nothing would open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First an irrelevant thing. The class "Task" may cause you problem because you already have `System.Threading.Task` in .net.

You shouldn't bind the ListView (or CollectionView) to a source twice for the same purpose as @Jason said.

**XAML FILE**

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MauiApp.Models"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiApp.Views"
    x:DataType="views:MainPage">

    <CollectionView            
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Task">
                <VerticalStackLayout Margin="15">
                    <Entry Text="{Binding name}" />
                    <Entry Text="{Binding status}" />
                    <Entry Text="{Binding deadline}" />
                    <Entry Text="{Binding description}" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

Check the XML namespaces (xmlns). I assumed you have your Task model inside "Models" folder and your views inside "Views" folder. You need this import because your content page's datatype is binded with `MainPage`, but your CollectionView is binded with `Task` class.

Inside DataTemplate you can have only 1 item. So you should choose a container item, like `VerticalStackLayout` in this answer.

**CLASS FILE**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Task>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;

        Tasks.Add(new Task("task 1", new List<string>() { "dep1", "dep2" }, "status 1", DateOnly.MinValue, "description 1"));
        Tasks.Add(new Task("task 2", new List<string>() { "dep3", "dep4" }, "status 2", DateOnly.MinValue, "description 2"));
    }
}
```

In your class you could use `ObservableCollection` and you must bind Context with `BindingContext = this;`

If you are using MVVM, than you can bind that to your ViewModel.

This should work as expected, although you may need to class OnPropertyChanged if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to put 2 entries in the same line but still divided?

Comment: Sure. You could nest different layouts. Horizontal, Vertical, Grids etc.. Only rule is, you can have only 1 item inside DataTemplate as root container. Just play around with it, until you have a nice layout arrangement.

Comment: How can I make it so, when I have more than one layout filled (more than one item on the list), it fills into the right rather than stacking them vertically?

Comment: you may be looking for FlexLayout. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/flexlayout?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 1):

a `ListView`'s `DataTemplate` can only contains a **single** child element.  If you want to have multiple data elements, use a [ViewCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells) instead of a `TextCell` and build your own custom layout

```
<ViewCell>
   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding image}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding title}"
                            TextColor="#f35e20" />
        <Label Text="{Binding subtitle}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            TextColor="#503026" />
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
   </ViewCell>
```